# create a array with same elements from a array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering if i can differentiate array elements in two or more different arrays like i have a array `$product_options`

```
$product_options: [
    {
      "option_id": "4",
      "title": "Color",
      "value_id": "10",
      "value_title": "Red",
      "price": "12.0000"
    },
    {
      "option_id": "4",
      "title": "Color",
      "value_id": "11",
      "value_title": "Green",
      "price": "13.0000"
    },
    {
      "option_id": "3",
      "title": "Size",
      "value_id": "7",
      "value_title": "S",
      "price": "12.0000"
    },
    {
      "option_id": "3",
      "title": "Size",
      "value_id": "8",
      "value_title": "M",
      "price": "13.0000"
    }
  ]
```

So in the above array i have four elements with two identical elements. I want to separate these two identical elements into two arrays. 
Desired Output:

```
$product_options:[
[{
      "option_id": "4",
      "title": "Color",
      "value_id": "10",
      "value_title": "Red",
      "price": "12.0000"
    },
    {
      "option_id": "4",
      "title": "Color",
      "value_id": "11",
      "value_title": "Green",
      "price": "13.0000"
    }],
[{
      "option_id": "3",
      "title": "Size",
      "value_id": "7",
      "value_title": "S",
      "price": "12.0000"
    },
    {
      "option_id": "3",
      "title": "Size",
      "value_id": "8",
      "value_title": "M",
      "price": "13.0000"
    }]
]
```

P.S My code is in json format but my query is in php only.

Comment: update your question with desired output

Comment: need some more explanation about your question.

Comment: This one does not look like PHP at all. More like JSON or something.

Comment: Both two comments are correct you should explain better what do you want to happen and this is javascript array and not PHP!

Comment: @BunkerBoy  i have updated with my desired output. code i posted is in json but my question is for php.

Comment: i think he has to group result according to options id..then show your back end php code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $data = array();
    foreach($product_options as $key => $value) {
        if(!key_exists($value["option_id"], $data)) {
            $data[$value["option_id"]] = array( $value );
        }
        else {
            $array = $data[$value["option_id"]];
            $array[] = $value;
            $data[$value["option_id"]] = $array;
        }
    }
    print_r($data);

    $final = array();
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $final[] = $value;
}
echo json_encode($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$groupedProductOptions = [];

foreach($product_options as $productOption) {
    $optionId = $productOption->option_id;

    if (!array_key_exists($optionId)) {
        $result[$optionId] = [];
    }

    $groupedProductOptions[$optionId][] = $productOption;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.